# Review before writing to database from UI

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, architecture

This is more of a question on design approach. I have an application which has the following details:

1. UI in Angular
2. UI uses an api which is in Node/Express
3. Database is just a JSON file for now.

I want to move to mongoDb from the JSON file. What I'd like is, whenever anyone uses the UI to make changes to the database, I'd like to review the changes before they are updated in the database. what is the best way to achieve this?

This was easier for me with the JSON file because I was creating a pull request on git where I would review all the changes and then update.

Things that I have thought:

1. Let the UI write to a separate clone collection(table) and then review them and update the main collection accordingly. Not sure if this is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you yourself wanting to review changes, or wanting an end user to review before saving? If it's *you*, you have a few options:

- **You can create a mongodb collection of pending objects** that will get moved to a different collection once they're approved. This is OK, but not great because you'll end up shuttling objects around and it's probably more reasonable to use a flag to do aggregate grouping instead of collection-based delineation
- **You can simply use a property on an object as a flag** and send objects that are pending review to your db with that flag enabled (using some property like `true`, 1, or another way of saying "this is true/on/enabled etc.")

If you want an end-user to be able to save, you can use mongoose hooks/middleware to fire off validators or whatever you want and return a response with meaningful data back to your angular UI. From there, you can have a user 'review' what they're saving. This doesn't persist or get saved, it's only saved once they send everything back up again (if that's how you choose to build the save process).

Comment: Yes I was thinking about a collection of pending objects. But I guess the flag approach might be a more elegant solution. Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: sure thing! also, IMO the pending objects one makes it tougher to do aggregations, since you'd be using collections as the bounding marker. There's also the aspect that it's less idiomatic to a NoSQL model — i.e. you should be able to have as many objects of a given type as you want and sort them by property :)

Comment: great! Happy to help :)